# What notification is stored in GoogleCheckout when an application is purchased via the Android Market?

Tags: android, google-checkout

I need to know the details of the XML response when an Application is purchased via the Android Market.

I understand that it is impossible to recieve the notifications directly but you are able to get them via the history API.

does anyone have an example response from the Google Checkout server?
In particular I need to know what is stored in item_name_1